# Inaccurate accelerometer update interval

Tags: iphone, ios, accelerometer, core-motion

I'm using the CoreMotion API and I would like to save the accelerometer's values every 10ms (100hz). The update intervals I obtained so far aren't accurate.
Here's an example of update intervals I got (in second):

```
0.010414999997
0.0105919999769
0.0117060000193
0.0198359999922
0.00989700001082
0.0100809999858
0.0100519999978
0.0106810000143
0.010420000006
0.0107459999854
0.0105899999908
0.0105130000156
0.0104829999909
0.0107439999992
0.010391000018
0.0105859999894
0.0102320000005
0.010134000011
0.0101929999946
0.010666999995
0.00996399999713
0.0123709999898
0.0181950000115
0.0107940000016
0.00988500000676
0.0101469999936
0.0103529999906
```

As you can see, some values are higher than 10ms.
Some more informations:
- Xcode 3.2.6 / iOS4.3 / armv7
- Tested on iPhone4 iOS5.1 and iPodTouch4 iOS4.3.3
- The source code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    started = NO;
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    if ([motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable]) {
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01; //100Hz
        motionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        [motionQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]; // Serial operation queue
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Accelerometer is not available!\n");
     }
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSMutableString *documentsDirectory = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[paths objectAtIndex:0]];
     path = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
     [path setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/timestamp.cap", documentsDirectory]];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];
}


- (IBAction) startStopButton:(id) sender {
    if(!started) {
        started = YES;
        [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CMAccelerometerHandler dataHandler = ^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
            NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f\n", accelerometerData.timestamp];
            NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
            [fh seekToEndOfFile];
            [fh writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [fh closeFile];
        };        
        [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:motionQueue withHandler:dataHandler];
    } else {
        started = NO;
        [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
        [motionQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
        [sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: why do you need an exact update interval? Omitting the three values of 12, 18 and 19 ms, the time seems to fluctuate nicely around 20ms...

Comment: The file will be analysed afterward for some reason. I know some app (like SensorData) can get an exact update interval.

Comment: Well, I did not use the accelerometer yet, but from my experiences with GPS, I know that all filters are not very accurate. You get updates whenever iOS feels like... I doubt that other applications get more accurate data, but they possibly pretend to...

Comment: You are logging all the readings of Accelerometer? for me im getting last value. I want to log all the values once i press the start button tp csv. once stop it should stop & write the value to the csv. Guide me in this.

Comment: Hi i know that the question is 4 years old but i am facing the same problem as you did.It is crucial for my application that the update interval must be equal to 11 ms and constant.So i wonder is there any solution to get that working.